# Getting multiple readings from .txt into excel

Tags: excel

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to ask this, but basically I have a .txt file containing values that came from 2 separate sensors. 
Example of some data:

```
{"t":3838202,"s":0,"n":"x1","v":-1052}
{"t":3838203,"s":0,"n":"y1","v":44}
{"t":3838204,"s":0,"n":"z1","v":-84}
{"t":3838435,"s":0,"n":"x1","v":-1052}
{"t":3838436,"s":0,"n":"y1","v":36}
{"t":3838437,"s":0,"n":"z1","v":-80}
{"t":3838670,"s":0,"n":"x1","v":-1056}
{"t":3838671,"s":0,"n":"y1","v":52}
{"t":3838672,"s":0,"n":"z1","v":-88}
{"t":3838902,"s":0,"n":"x1","v":-1052}
{"t":3838903,"s":0,"n":"y1","v":48}
{"t":3838904,"s":0,"n":"z1","v":-80}
{"t":3839136,"s":0,"n":"x1","v":-1056}
{"t":3839137,"s":0,"n":"y1","v":40}
{"t":3839138,"s":0,"n":"z1","v":-80}
x2:-944                       
y2:108                        
z2:-380                       
{"t":3839841,"s":0,"n":"x1","v":-1052}
{"t":3839842,"s":0,"n":"y1","v":44}
{"t":3839843,"s":0,"n":"z1","v":-80}
x2:-948                       
y2:100                        
z2:-380                       
{"t":3840541,"s":0,"n":"x1","v":-1052}
{"t":3840542,"s":0,"n":"y1","v":40}
{"t":3840543,"s":0,"n":"z1","v":-84}
{"t":3840774,"s":0,"n":"x1","v":-1052}
{"t":3840775,"s":0,"n":"y1","v":40}
{"t":3840776,"s":0,"n":"z1","v":-84}
x2:-948                       
y2:108                        
z2:-368
```

I'm trying to get the data into excel, so that for each "chunk" of data in the x1y1z1 section, I take the last set of recorded data and discard the rest and "pair" it with the next set of x2y2z2 data. I don't think I'm explaining it very well, but I basically want to take that text file and get this in excel:

```
+---------+-------+----+-----+------+-----+------+
|    t    |  x1   | y1 | z1  |  x2  | y2  |  z2  |
+---------+-------+----+-----+------+-----+------+
| 3839138 | -1056 | 40 | -80 | -944 | 100 | -380 |
| 3839843 | -1052 | 44 | -80 | -948 | 100 | -380 |
| 3840776 | -1052 | 40 | -84 | -948 | 108 | -368 |
+---------+-------+----+-----+------+-----+------+
```

I'm really stuck as to where I should even start

Comment: Something like this can be done with Power Query

Answer (score 0):

I think like a programmer, so I would approach this problem in steps.  If you are not a programmer, this might not be so helpful to you, and I am sorry for that.

- First, define the data.  How does each line of data get read and understood.
- Second, write a parsing utility.  A piece of code which interprets the data as it is read in and stores it in the form you want for your output
- Third, import data into Excel.

So, based on the limited data you provided, I am not sure how you are able to determine the x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2 for each t, but I assume that the values enclosed in curly braces have something to do with that based on the values for s, n, and v I'm seeing in there.  So, first of all you need to clearly determine the way you read the data.  Take it one line at a time, and determine how you would build your output table based on each line of data.  I assume you would treat the lines enclosed in curly braces differently from the lines with standalone x/y/z values for example.

I hope this points you in the right direction.